# EJB 3 Static reference or Runtime lookup?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am calling an EJB from a POJO making a JNDI lookup.I want to know what is a better way to make the lookup and what are the implications of each way? I have 2 options

1. In the static block of POJO ,make a static reference to an EJB and use this static reference in all objects

   ```
    public class MyPojo
   {      
   static  {   
       MyEJB ejb = (MyEJB) EJBServiceLocatorUtil.fetchService(IAppConstants.JNDI_LOCAL);
       }
        .....
   }
   ```
2. Make a JNDI lookup everytime I create a new object

   ```
   public class MyPojo
   {
   public MyPojo(){
       MyEJB ejb = (MyEJB)     EJBServiceLocatorUtil.fetchService(IAppConstants.JNDI_LOCAL);
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 could fail if the EJB is not deployed yet or if the JNDI context is not available. There could be portability issue from one app server to another.

Option 2 could be time consuming (JNDI lookup) depending on how often you instantiate MyPojo.

Another option could be to use the implementation of the singleton pattern of Bill Plugh: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh where Singleton is your EJB. The JNDI lookup is done only once and lazily (on first call).

Note that all these options are only valid for stateless session beans.